# Arduino Magnetic Vent + Ethernet Shield --> Vent closes at new client

Tags: networking, arduino

I am working with the Arduino Ethernet Shield 2 and an Magnetic Vent for Waterpipes.

The problem I have is that as soon as a new Client occurs at the Arduino the Vent closes and opens again immediately. Normally it would disturb me but the Vent makes really strange noises while openning and I don't want that everytime.

[Here is the link to my Github repo .ino File](https://github.com/matthias-schneglberger/Wasserstandsleser/blob/master/Wasserstand_master/Wasserstand_master.ino)

I hope you can help me!

Comment: pin 50 is used by the shield. it is SPI MISO. https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SPI

Comment: THANK you ... that problem took several days